# New EC2 vsftpd installation will not start, giving code=exited, status=2

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, ftp, redhat, vsftpd

I am trying to implement an FTP server on an EC2 instance.  I cannot get the FTP server to start and it gives me very little idea of what is wrong.  I'd appreciate any information on either how to resolve the problem or, at least, how to debug it.

I am going to use S3 storage to receive files, but FTP hasn't touched that yet.

I believe the installation went fine.  If there could be an issue there, let me know.

Thanks!

Attempt to start:

```
$ sudo chkconfig vsftpd on
Note: Forwarding request to 'systemctl enable vsftpd.service'.
$ sudo service vsftpd start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  vsftpd.service
Job for vsftpd.service failed. See 'systemctl status vsftpd.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

So, show me what is wrong?  Not much...

```
$ systemctl status vsftpd.service
vsftpd.service - Vsftpd ftp daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2015-11-16 16:39:41 EST; 8s ago
  Process: 2178 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf (code=exited, status=2)
$ journalctl -xn
No journal files were found.
```

Do you have ftpsecure available?

```
$ cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd
root
...
ec2-user
ftpsecure

cat /etc/passwd
...
ftpsecure:x:1001:1001::/home/ftpsecure:/sbin/nologin
```

Show the configuration file:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=077
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chown_uploads=YES
chown_username=ec2-user
xferlog_file=/var/log/xferlog
log_ftp_protocol = YES
xferlog_std_format=NO
nopriv_user=ftpsecure
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=NO
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd/user_list
userlist_deny=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
```

Access to the files would be:

```
$ ls -ld vsftpd
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 102 Nov 16 17:09 vsftpd
$ ls -l *
-rw-r--r--. 1 ftpsecure root    8 Nov 16 16:57 chroot_list
-rw-------. 1 ftpsecure root  125 Mar  7  2014 ftpusers
-rw-------. 1 ftpsecure root  361 Mar  7  2014 user_list
-rw-------. 1 ftpsecure root 5099 Nov 16 17:04 vsftpd.conf
-rwxr--r--. 1 root      root  338 Mar  7  2014 vsftpd_conf_migrate.sh
$ ls -ld log
drwxrwxrwx. 8 root root 4096 Nov 16 16:43 log
$ ls -l vsftpd.log
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 ec2-user ec2-user 0 Nov 16 16:43 vsftpd.log
```

File access:

```
$ sudo touch chroot_list
$ sudo touch ftpusers
$ sudo touch user_list
$ sudo touch vsftpd.conf
$ sudo touch /var/log/vsftpd.log
```

List the files

```
$ cat chroot_list
private
$ sudo cat ftpusers
# Users that are not allowed to login via ftp
root
bin
daemon
adm
lp
sync
shutdown
halt
mail
news
uucp
operator
games
nobody
$ sudo cat user_list
# vsftpd userlist
# If userlist_deny=NO, only allow users in this file
# If userlist_deny=YES (default), never allow users in this file, and
# do not even prompt for a password.
# Note that the default vsftpd pam config also checks /etc/vsftpd/ftpusers
# for users that are denied.
root
bin
daemon
adm
lp
sync
shutdown
halt
mail
news
uucp
operator
games
nobody
$ cat vsftpd.log
$
```

Comment: Status 2 should mean "No such file or directory."  Either /usr/sbin/vsftpd itself, or one of the files it tries to open, seems to be missing. Running `$ sudo /usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf` should say *something* useful.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot  Well, that helped right off.  Please post as answer.  If you would, please provide a reference where the Status codes are provided, too.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Michael Well, my joy was short lived.  Now, it fails with status 1...

Comment: Error 1 is often used as a very general error code, for things like invalid arguments, failed to parse configuration files, etc.  Technically, it means "Operation not permitted."  One of my projects is an error code reference site with in-depth explanations, but it's not ready for release, yet, so I'll just say search Google for "linux error codes."